# Is there a best practice to store content of attribute value to HTML event?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I would like to store the content of attribute value (which is red) to an HTML event as parameter. Is there a **best practice** to do this instead of put it manually as a parameter ?

```
<input type="radio" value="red" onchange="changeColor('red')">
```

Comment: In a generic sense it would be more usual to pass a reference to the element with `changeColor(this)` and then let the function access whichever attributes it wants. But it would be better to *not* use inline `onchange` attributes, instead binding a single delegated event handler to the radio button group's parent element.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @nnnnnn

Comment: HTML inline events aren't best practice as besides making a mess of your markup it's an overlap of roles. HTML should be used only for document structure not functionallity or style as those are the role of JS and CSS respectively. It's fine to use the value attribute however you should definitely not replicate the value within the event handler - you're better referencing/accessing value attribute from within your event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Hope it helps!

```
<input type="radio" value="red" onclick="changeColor(this.value)">
```

Comment: using `onchange` is not a modern day *"best practice"*

Comment: @charlietfl not sure why he's using onchange there, but just replaced it with onclick as an example. Thanks

Comment: onkeyup for radio ?? My point was that inline script is not a modern best practice

Comment: @charlietfl Oops I thought it was type="text" my bad. Just updated it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the value as an argument you can pass it using `this.value`

Alternatively you can assign the default value in function argument & pass the `value` attribute if it is other than default value

HTML

```
<input type="radio" value="red" name='radio' onchange="changeColor(this.value)">
<input type="radio" value="red" name='radio' onchange="changeColor()">
```

**JS**

```
//setting defualt value as red
function changeColor(color = 'red'){
      console.log(color);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think event delegation and binding a click event via JS is without a doubt the best practice solution. as it uses a single function, and minimizes repetition.

Using HTML for event handling is messy as you end up repeating a functions name many times especially in cases like this also it's not really HTML's role to add functionality - that's JS' role. HTML is there to provide a documents structure primarily.

As others have stated using a click event is best practice as behavior of onchange varies from browser to browser.

Below is a complete example of working inputs, JS bound delegated event which will log out the value of any input within `#radioColours`

```js
var dynamicBind = document.getElementById("radioColours");
dynamicBind.addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  var elem = evt.target;
  if(elem.tagName == "INPUT"){
    console.log(elem.value)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="radioColours">
  Red - <input type="radio" name="colours" value="red"><br>
  Blue -<input type="radio" name="colours" value="blue"><br>
</div>
```